# I can't block a port with ufw

Tags: port, udp, ufw

This morning I received a report from Netscan:

```
Netscan detected from host 8X.19X.1X.1XX
time protocol src_ip  src_port dest_ip dest_port
Fri Sep 15 05:21:59 2023 UDP 8X.19X.1X.1XX 5065 => 9.87.179.94 5060
```

Despite the fact that I have blocked the port as follows.

I blocked port `5060`:

```
5060:5068/udp (v6) DENY Anywhere (v6)
5060:5068/udp DENY Anywhere
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: So? There is no problem here. Portscans are the background noise of the internet. It's not worth it trying to stop this. Also, you appear to be blocking only UDP, where this "scan" could have been TCP.

Comment: Also, there is no need to create a rule for every port you want to close, just set the `ufw default` accordingly.

Comment: @Panki Thanks you very much: In fact, I've just priced the interesting part as UDP, but I've also configured it as TCP.

But how can I block the leaks that always use this port?

Comment: It isn't possible to stop port scans on a system with a connection to the internet. The only thing that can be done is to not have the port open which you have already done. What is done on other systems can't be controlled unless the connection to the internet on your system is removed.

Comment: @NasirRiley thanks (The only thing that can be done is to not have the port open which you have already done) you very much.

Comment: No problem. I've added it as an answer with more details and clarity. You can accept it it's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to stop port scans on a system with a connection to the internet. The only thing that can be done is to not have the port open which you have already done but even that just means that the port isn't accessible and not that it isn't open to port scans. The internet connection is what allows that to happen. With that being said, what is done on other systems can't be controlled and unless the connection to the internet on your system is removed, it will be open to port scans.